# Help identifying CSUN solar cell and how to use it (preparation, setup etc.)

Tags: identification, solar-cell

My brother has come into a pallet of solar cells that I can't identify exactly.  They seem to have both sides covered so I'm unclear how they are supposed to be used. Getting a lot of false positives in my searching as I'm unsure exactly what to look for.

Here is the packaging it came in.

[image: Packaging and label]

Here are images of the cell itself.

[image: front or back of solar cell]
[image: back or front of solar cell]

I guess what's confusing me is why it's coated in white on both sides. I would guess the side with all the small white lines is what you are supposed to connect to?

Does it look this way because it's not laminated to anything yet? What would the process be to get them usable? Does the coating need to be removed somehow before they can be used?

Comment: Have you tried contacting CSUN or might there be trouble if you do?

Comment: I did just send them an email.  I'm not holding my breath though. These were picked up at an auction.

Comment: I expect one surface is positive and the other negative.  It looks like "HPPL" ordered these in January 2009.  perhaps they used some?

Comment: I'm seeing the familiar blue in the top left corner. If there's a cracked one (you say they are delicate) I'd investigate to see if there's some protective peel-off film over the rest of it.

Comment: Wasn't trying to, but it really didn't take much to break it... The white seems to be some kind of powder coating maybe. It scrapes off with some difficulty and there is a metalic sheen under that. Haven't tried heat yet, maybe it melts away when soldering/heating. Would be nice to have more information before destroying more of them.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if these are ruggedized panels with a diffusion polysilicate layer used for roads recently. https://www.polyu.edu.hk/cpa/greendeck/pdf/14_Prof_HX_Yang_Research_and_development_of_solar_PV_pavement_for_application_on_Green_Deck.pdf

The best way is to test for Voc and Isc.

Comment: Date 2009-03-30, so probably not.

Comment: Not sure what would count as 'rugged'.  These are extremely delicate.

Comment: Then not the same or needs a substrate.